# Loop does not terminate when string matches

Tags: c

loop not working, any answers please, some variables are not used ..i know, but it will not get out of the loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main(){

    char name;
    int Employees=0, idnum;
    float Low=99999, High=0, earnings, Tearnings=0, Avgearnings;


    while(name != "xxxx"){


        if(earnings < Low)
        {
            Low = earnings;
        }


        if (earnings > High)
        {
            High = earnings;

        }


    printf("Enter name\n"); 
    scanf("%s", &name);

    printf("Enter earnings\n"); 
    scanf("%f", &earnings);


    Tearnings = Tearnings / earnings;
    Employees = Employees ++;

    }


    Avgearnings = Tearnings / Employees;

    printf("Average earnings: %2f", Avgearnings);
    printf("Lowest Earnings: %2f", Low);
    printf("Highest earnings: %2f", High);


    return 0;   
}
```

it will not exit the loop

Comment: `name != "xxxx"` that's not how you compare strings

Comment: You really should enable warning when you compile

Comment: Try to turn it off and turn it back on again :) Or use strcmp

Answer (score 0):

You are using a while loop without any real break condition.

You should either add a `if (xxx) {break}` or change it to `var i;
for (i=0, i < earnings.length ; i++) { ... }` by doing this, it should have the program process through all of your employees/earnings, and move on after it gets to the last one.